# How to backup and restore Alfresco Community when running using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I'm starting using alfresco community content service using Docker,
I'm blind at this because I'm also doesn't know about Docker. So how about backing up and restoring alfresco database when running in docker? My Environment is Linux Centos 7.

Comment: Is your existing Alfresco is docker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read and understand [Backing up and restoring the repository](https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/backup-intro.html) first.
If you don't have any experience with docker you may prefer the non dockerized style in production. I haven't seen dockerized alfresco in production so far since most it departments don't have any docker experience and prefer vms. There is a nice install script for ubuntu called [alfresco-ubuntu-install](https://github.com/loftuxab/alfresco-ubuntu-install). Maybe this is a better starting point.

Alfresco backup in short:

A consistent alfresco backup contains (in the order of creation):

- solr-backup (created by solr REST-API or by Alfresco quarz jobs defined in alfresco-global.properties)
- db dump
- alf_data/contentstore (or you create snapshots on your storage tier)

if you run the dockerized alfresco you can do everything from your docker host if you installed postgresql-client

e.g.

```
PGPASSWORD=alfresco pg_dump -U alfresco -d alfresco -h localhost > alfresco.sql
```

Comment: When I run the command it says connection refused, is the server running on host 127.0.0.1 and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432 (this port is the default port in the docker-compose.yaml). I tried without the port and the result is the same, how to check my postgres database host name? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have already running a postgres db on the docker host? I tested with the docker-compose.yaml from alfresco 6.1 which worked for me to login from docker host localhost:5432 the port is mapped transparently: https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-deployment/blob/master/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml